# Reading from a text file using PHP, adding to MySQL DB Problem

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have the following PHP code that allows me to read in from a text file line by line and write to a MySQL database. The text file consists of 13 values seperated by a space on each line. I have created the table separately in SQL, (with all the relevant Fields needed: Time, WIMU_ID, Ax, Ay etc) and then run the PHP below to INSERT the values into the table. My question is: Is there any way to create the table within the PHP code below and not have to CREATE the table in SQL first? Any help or suggestions appreciated.
Hugh.

```
<?php

    $connection  = mysql_connect('localhost','root','bonzo123');
    mysql_query('create database gameDB');
    mysql_select_db('gameDB');

    $wx = array_map('trim',file("Thu-Apr-01-09_41_01-2010.txt_calibrated_120Hz.txt"));
    $newwx = array();
    foreach($wx as $i => $line)
    {
            if ($i > 1)
            {
                    $tmp = array_filter(explode(' ',$line));
                    $q = "insert into test1 (Time, WIMU_ID, Ax, Ay, Az, Gx, Gy, Gz, Mx, My, Mz, Ax70, Ay37) values ('" . implode("','",$tmp) . "')";
                    $rw = mysql_query($q) or die("Problem with the query: $q<br>" . mysql_error());
            }
    }
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can execute a command like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1`  (
...
);
```

To get your table creation query, issue this command after you've already created it in SQL:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `test1`;
```

**Edit:**

Note that you don't have to create the table in SQL directly, but since you already have, issuing the above command will give you exactly what you need to include in PHP to have it create the table on a future installation should the table not exist.

Note also that as @Jeremy suggests, you don't have to "roll your own" code to import a data file to a table. Once you've created the table, you can use `LOAD DATA INFILE...` to populate the table.

**Edit 2:**

Here is an example based on your comment:

```
<?php
// Connect to the database server
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'bonzo123');
if (!$connection)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

// Create database gameDB
if (mysql_query('create database gameDB', $connection)) {
    echo "Database gameDB created successfully.\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n:";
}

// select which database to use
mysql_select_db('gameDB', $connection);

// create table test1 if it doesn't already exist
mysql_query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1 (
    v1 varchar(100),
    v2 varchar(100),
    v3 varchar(100),
    v4 varchar(100),
    v5 varchar(100),
    v6 varchar(100),
    v7 varchar(100),
    v8 varchar(100),
    v9 varchar(100),
    v10 varchar(100)', $connection);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I do this do I still have to create the table in SQL first?

Comment: No, you just need create permissions for your login. Since you're using 'root' that should be no problem.

Comment: <?php
        $connection  = mysql_connect('localhost','root','bonzo123');
        mysql_query('create database gameDB');
        mysql_select_db('gameDB');
        $mysql_query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test1(v1 varchar(100),v2 varchar(100),v3 varchar(100),v4 varchar(100),v5 varchar(100),v6 varchar(100),v7  varchar(100),v8 varchar(100),v9 varchar(100),v10 varchar(100),$
        $useDB = mysql_query('USE gamedata');
?>
Something like that?

Comment: Hard to tell from comments formatting (I realize you can't edit your question) but that looks about right. There shouldn't be a `$` in front of mysql_query(...) and just after `v10` there's another oddly placed `$` but otherwise good. I'll format this how I think you want it and add to my answer.

Comment: Hi I tried the above suggestion but it wont create the table with that "CREATE IF NOT EXIST" command. I havent been able to find any info on that command is that correct? I got the following error. Again I appreciate the help.                             Database gameDB created successfully. Problem with the query: insert into test1 (Time, WIMU_ID, Ax, Ay, Az, Gx, Gy, Gz, Mx, My, Mz, Ax70, Ay37) values ('1270111261.3267093','2','0.603745','0.028351','0.310371','2052.000000','2037.182182','2046.591091','-0.909519','0.334003','-0.190586','1.102227','-0.025425')
Table 'gamedb.test1' doesn't exist

Comment: The syntax for creating tables is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html. I executed the create table statement without a problem. You may want to add an if statement to that line and echo the `mysql_error()` to see if your db is allowing you to create the table (or hint at the problem).

Comment: Also your insert statement contains 13 values, where the table (at least in my example) only has 10 columns. Next, why are you using `varchar` for every column type? Your data appears to be timestamp, int and decimal in nature.

Comment: As embarrassing as it is, turns out I was missing a single ")" from my code. It works now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

which you can invoke through PHP but this would be a lot better unless you have specific reasons it cannot be used.

Comment: It looks like the lion's share of the data is in the form of taking a text file and putting it into MYSQL.  Using PHP as a middleman for handling each row will be very inefficient, and I would not recommend it unless you absolutely had to.  Much easier to bulk load the data through the db engine and then run tweaks through code.

Comment: I am hoping to read in other data that is not as well structured using a similar method. Where the data looks like this:       Frame_0100
X_coordinates
23.90,23.90,23.94,23.98,24.02,24.02,24.06
Y_coordinates
5.55,6.15,5.55,5.55,5.51,5.55,5.51
Z_coordinates
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00
Frame_0101
X_coordinates
23.90,23.90,23.94,23.98,24.02,24.02,24.06
Y_coordinates
5.55,6.15,5.55,5.55,5.51,5.55,5.51
Z_coordinates
0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00                                   and so on. Can SQL handle the data like this?

Comment: I will create another question thread for this enquiry. Thanks for your help.